# on the means of deploying the Apache Airflow platform

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Could anybody please share experience/views on the means of deploying the Apache Airflow platform (in its simpest standalone mode using sequential executor) on the production server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think SequentialExecutor mode is the right one for production server. We have one running in a LocalExecutor mode in production, and it works quite well. LocalExecutor mode can do everything that SequentialExecutor does and more.

Comment: Could you please share the cons you can think of regarding the SequentialExecutor mode for a production server? We just need to run sequentially a number of scripts once a month or so and it seems to be the simplest solution that is just right (though I can easily believe that we overlooked somewhat important). Thanks

Comment: If you don't foresee any future need for parallelism, I guess its possible to use Airflow in this way.